# Approval Process Update conflicting with validation rule

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, approval-process, before-save-flow

I have a flow that automatically fires an approval process that needs unanimous approvals from three different managers. When the Opportunity enters stage 5, this before-save record triggered flow fires and it looks for the Opportunity products with specific products. It the criteria is satisfied, the flow is performing a field update (checking a checkbox "Product Approval Required" on the Opportunity") and then fires the approval process. The approval process sends the approval emails to three different managers for approval. When the first two managers approve, nothing happens. When the last manager approves, the approval proces is trying to update the picklist field "Product Approval Status" to "Approved". However, this update fails as there are multiple validation rules on the Opportunity when the Opportunity enters stage 5.

At this point, the approval process has the Opportunity record in locked status. So, even though the validation rule says which field is causing the issue, the user is not able to fix the data. So, in short, the approval process is not able to update the Opportunity due to validation rule and the user is not able to fix the data as the approval process has locked the Opportunity resulting in a catch-22 situation.

Can someone help? I was thinking of changing the validation rule to catch the data issues at stage 4, but I am not sure how many validation rules I need to change. There are over 150 validation rules on the Opportunity object and when I manually testing this flow & approval process, 7 validation rules fired. Depending on the type of Opportunity and the data, more validation rules could fire.